# Can't use SharedPreferences variable outside of the MainActivity class

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a simple app which requires me to remember all checkbox states which are dynamically generated.
I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to save the states of these, I'm using an recyclerview, so I've defined my sharedpreferences and all in the mainactivity which extends Activity.
All good and well, now I'm trying to use this in my Adapter class by trying referencing `MainActivity.data`, without luck.

MainActivity relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public static String FILENAME = "AnimeConfig";
    public SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new GetAnime().execute();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }

    private class GetAnime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String animeUrl = "http://www.animeseason.com/anime-list";
        public List<String> animes = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(animeUrl).get();
                Elements elements = document.select("div.series_alpha span");
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    animes.add(element.previousElementSibling().text());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(animes);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
}
```

MyAdapter relevant code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mDataset;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox mCheckbox;

        public ViewHolder(CheckBox v) {
            super(v);
            mCheckbox = v;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(List<String> animes) {
        mDataset = animes;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        CheckBox v = (CheckBox) LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mCheckbox.setText(mDataset.get(position));

        holder.mCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    String animeName = buttonView.getText().toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MainActivity.data.edit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I can't use `MainActivity.data`.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare SharedPreferences data as static so you can access it from other classes .

but i prefer to use helper class to do all this work for me

something like this :

```
public class GeneralHelper {

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPrefrence(Context contextversion) {
       //do the code for getting SharedPreferences    
    }

}
```

Comment: When I declare it as static (`public static SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);`), it tells me you can't make it static.
It says can't call non-static method from static context.

Comment: instead of that , simply you can put some method like this `public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(DONDON_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }` in your MainActivity and call it when ever you want @voider1

Comment: the error you get happen beacuse getSharedPreferences() is method of Activity.class but it doesn't have static declaration @voider1